They come in twos
Which two big ones are missing here?
57,39,36,4,73,77,84,90,30,7,86,73,6,33,71,57,79,89,27,9,4,15,29,35,88,84,31,3,62,69,14,32,49,33,80,59,62,48,76,83,32,46,47,4,5,38,79,100,47,19,76,97,2,32,99,74,20,8,31,3,93,75,61,17,78,56,18,12,85,65,0,23,8,15,46,0,98,80,58,65,100,76,82,80,37,52,0,13,37,2,54,15,0,16,18,30,2,20,59,12,67,71,70,76,52,64,45,59,14,13,13,11,46,28,48,25,9,37,77,91,91,68,87,90,76,100,25,34,60,7,77,61

The missing ones are ...

 ... Sicily and Sardinia.

If we ...

 ... take pairs of values from the list and plot them as x and y positions in a scatter plot, we get:



 This looks like the outline of mainland Italy. (The linked article takes its time to show a useful map where you can see the outline. Here is a direct link.) Italy has several islands and the two biggest ones, which could be represented with the given granularity, are Sicily and Sardinia.

 (My first idea was to plot the points as a polygon, but they don't seem to be in order. If there is a way to plot the points in order, I haven't found it. Anyway, the points are dense enough that the shape can be recognised.)

The title ...

 ... tells us that we should use the given numbers in pais, but it's also a confirmation of the answer: The Italian penninsula looks like a boot and boots come in pairs, too. (Although Italy is one of a kind, of course.)


(I originally had them ordered, but lookin at it I feared it would be too obvious what to do, so I opted for this version instead. FWIW here's the polygon)
